# Excel SUMPRODUCT works for 2021, but not 2020

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR(Infra_SIM[Request Date])=2021),--(TEXT(MONTH(Infra_SIM[Request Date]),"mmm")="Jan"),--(Infra_SIM[Use For Reporting]="Yes"))
```

This uses the named table and works fine, gives 13 as expected.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR(Infra_SIM[Request Date])=2020),--(TEXT(MONTH(Infra_SIM[Request Date]),"mmm")="Dec"),--(Infra_SIM[Use For Reporting]="Yes"))
```

Same exact formula for 2020, doesn't work.  It gives me 0 and it should give 12.

What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: There are many possibilities.  the 2020 dates may be stored as text and not true dates. or the `Yes` has a space before or after.  Most likely it is data related and not the formula and as such we can only guess as we do not have your data.

Comment: use the Evaluate Formula tool and step through the formula and see where it returns data that is different than expected.

Comment: This is the first time I have ever beaten Scott Craner on an answer. Still +1 because the Evaluate Formula tool would have caught this.

Comment: Remove the `MONTH` here and call `TEXT` on the actual date. Or use `MONTH` and compare to `12` as outlined in the posted answer. But don't mix `MONTH` and `TEXT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the year that's the problem, it's the month.

You wrapped it in the TEXT function and it's not evaluating as an array (it's all returning the first date).

To fix it change

`--(TEXT(MONTH(table[column]),"mmm"="Dec"))`

To

`--(MONTH(table[column])=12)`

Edit:

BigBen has pointed out that the issue isn't the TEXT() function, it's that MONTH() and TEXT() are nested in each other.

`--(TEXT(table[column],"mmm")="Dec")` is an equally valid solution.

Comment: I think you've hit on the problem, because passing the result of `MONTH` to `TEXT` doesn't make any sense.